# date not entered into db through DatePicker

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an appointments system with a date picker. My issues are:

- When I click the submit button, the selected date is not persisted into the database, though no error shows up.
- I am unable to line break the submit button.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui-1.10.4.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">    
            <input  type="text" name="date" id="Datepicker1">    
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php
            include ('db.php');
            $result = $conn->query("select tea_id, username from tea");
            echo "<select required name='tea_id'>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
                    //unset($id, $name);
                    $id = $row['tea_id'];
                    $name = $row['username'];
                    echo '<option value="">None</option>';
                    echo '<option  value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
        include ('db.php');
        session_start();

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit']) != "") {
            $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
            $new_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
            $tea_id = $_POST['tea_id'];
            {
                $query = mysqli_query(
                    $conn,
                    "INSERT INTO app (date,time,par_id,tea_id) VALUES ('$new_date','".$_SESSION['par_id']."','$tea_id')"
                );
                if($query) {
                    header("location:app.php");
                    echo " Successfully";
                } else {
                    echo " faliure";
                    // die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $( "#Datepicker1" ).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see you have four columns name while you are entering only three values in insert query

Comment: Given that the query seems to be malformed, you should see `faliure` on your page after submitting the form.

Comment: @bharatparmar thx it works now!!! i need to add a line break after the <select> and before the submit button...can u pls help me

Comment: There seems to have a closing `</select>` tag missing and orphan curly braces.

Comment: I cleaned up your code: https://pastebin.com/D7fsUAWu Even if you don't care about the rewriting, you should at the very least use proper indentation. The code you posted was an unreadable mess, which makes debugging it much harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your php code with this one:

```
<?php
  include ('db.php');
  $result = $conn->query("select tea_id, username from tea");
  echo "<select required name='tea_id'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
      //unset($id, $name);
      $id = $row['tea_id'];
      $name = $row['username'];
      echo '<option value="">None</option>';
      echo '<option  value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
  echo "</select>";
  echo "</br>";
?>
```

Comment: A little explanation of what you did could be helpful for OP or other users

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem you already identified in your comment...? And the "None" option is still echoed inside the loop.

Comment: select tag was not closed in question , so i mentioned it in above my answer